# Rails ActiveRecord. how can I deal with belong_to more than one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, belongs-to

How can I define a Person model so that any Person can be assigned as the parent of another Person (as demonstrated in the Rails console below)? What columns would you need to define in the migration creating the table for Person?

```
irb(main):001:0> john = Person.create(name: "John")
irb(main):002:0> jim = Person.create(name: "Jim", parent: john)
irb(main):003:0> bob = Person.create(name: "Bob", parent: john)
irb(main):004:0> john.children.map(&:name)
=> ["Jim", "Bob"]
```

I unserstand than the answer is something around

```
class People < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :children, class_name: "People", foreign_key: "parent_id"
        belongs_to :parent, class_name: "People" #Question HERE? how to deal with belong_to more than one?
end

class AddXXTOXXX <ActiveRecord::Migration
            def change
                create_table :peoples do |t|
                    t.add_column :name, string
                    t.add_column :parent, string
                    t.references :parent, index: true
                    t.timestamps
                end
            end
end
```

But what confused me is that everyone has two parents(mom and daddy), so does belongs_to still work in this case of scenario ?

Comment: I think this link should help you https://heurionconsulting.wordpress.com/2007/05/29/using-belongs_to-to-connect-different-classes/

Answer (score 1):

No, if you have multiple parents who can have multiple children, `belongs_to` is not appropriate.

You want `has_many through:...` which will use a join table... you can call it whatever you want but `relationships` seems appropriate.

Also, change your `People` class into `Person` class to follow rails conventions.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :ancestors, class_name: 'Relationship', foreign_key: :child_id
  has_many :descendants, class_name: 'Relationship', foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :parents, through: :ancestors, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :children, through: :descendants, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: :child_id

end
```

You can store additional information in the 'Relationship' table, if you want, such as "mother" or "father" and "son" or "daughter"... although that may be better inferred from Person sex if that exists.